# Generate a crosstab type dataframe with a binary count value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
UIID  ISBN
a      12
b      13
```

I want to compare each UUID with the ISBN and add a count column in the dataframe.

```
UUID ISBN Count
 a     12   1
 a     13   0
 b     12   0
 b     13   1
```

How can this be done in pandas. I know the crosstab function does the same thing but I want the data in this format.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['UIID'], df['ISBN']).reset_index().melt('UIID', value_name='count')
print (df)
  UIID ISBN  count
0    a   12      1
1    b   12      0
2    a   13      0
3    b   13      1
```

Alternative solution with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
s = df.groupby(['UIID','ISBN']).size()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(s.index.levels, names=s.index.names)
df = s.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
  UIID  ISBN  count
0    a    12      1
1    a    13      0
2    b    12      0
3    b    13      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pd.DataFrame.unstack`:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.UIID, df.ISBN).unstack().reset_index()
print(df)
   ISBN UIID  0
0    12    a  1
1    12    b  0
2    13    a  0
3    13    b  1
```